# Write on Firebase Database that user clicked button on listView item

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I have a listView with a custom adapter that includes text + button on each item of my list view. I'am retrieving the text from firebase without problem, but i want that if the user clicks on the button of a item, it will write on the database that that user clicked on that item.

Thank you if someone can help me, give me an idea or send a link.

I had an idea of retrieving the index(rec_1, rec_2, rec_3, etc) of the messages i'm putting on the listView and if the user clicks on the button, i write on the database index - userId : 1 or something like that, but how would i put the index value hidden on each item of the listview so i can retrieve when the button is clicked? Is just an ideia, if there is a better alternative, please tell me!
[image]

My code:

activity_recados_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRecados"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRecadoVisto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textRecados"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Visto" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

RecadosCustomAdapter.java

```
public class RecadosCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> recadosList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;


    public RecadosCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> recadosList, Context context) {
        this.recadosList = recadosList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return recadosList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return recadosList.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //return recadosList.get(pos).getId();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recados_item, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textRecados);
        listItemText.setText(recadosList.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        Button buttonVisto = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonRecadoVisto);

        buttonVisto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

RecadosActivity.java

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = myRef.limitToLast(15).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            ArrayList<String> recadosList = new ArrayList<String>();
            RecadosCustomAdapter adapter = new RecadosCustomAdapter(recadosList, RecadosActivity.this);

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                recadosList.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    RecadosInformation rInfo = new RecadosInformation();
                    rInfo.setData(ds.getValue(RecadosInformation.class).getData());
                    rInfo.setMensagem(ds.getValue(RecadosInformation.class).getMensagem());

                    Log.d(TAG, "showData: Data: " + rInfo.getData());
                    Log.d(TAG, "showData: Mensagem: " + rInfo.getMensagem());

                    recadosList.add(rInfo.getData() + "\n" + rInfo.getMensagem() + "\n");

                }
                Collections.reverse(recadosList);
                recados.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Thank you if someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do:
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("YOUR_NODE").child("child").setValue(yourvalue);

I think you get the idea?
Read here for more:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

**Edit** you'll know inside the getView method, that method is called for each item in the list so when u click a button, use the **int position** to get the particular position of the item

Do:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recados_item, null);
    }

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list
    TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textRecados);
    listItemText.setText(recadosList.get(position));

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    Button buttonVisto = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonRecadoVisto);

    buttonVisto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //upload the index which is position
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

**Edit 2** give each message an id on firebase database using the push().getKey() method. So in ur getView() do:

```
String id = yourlist.get(position).getId();
```

Then do what u want with it.

Comment: I understand, but how will i know which message has been clicked on the listView? So i can put on the database that that message that was clicked was "read"

Comment: So i will generate and retrieve an id on firebase with push().getKey() and i will relate to int position and my user?If so, this will work even if i'm using myRef.limitToLast(15) and the messages on the listView will be changing? How would i know which mensage is in that position? Sorry if i'm being annoying

Comment: Sorry what are u actually trying to write to database. If I click on a button in one of the item, what should happen??

Comment: I'm retrieving the 15 latest messages, when the user clicks on the button of one item on the listView, i want to put on the database that the user confirmed that they read that message clicked. Did you understand? English is not my first language

Comment: Thats why each message have an identification. Because you need it to write to database that user have read a message

Comment: Yes, you're right. So how do I know which message I clicked on the listView to be able to update the identification in the database?

Comment: Right now u can only know the position. But there's no unique thing about each message